# Efficiently merge a dataframe with another by selecting the second dataframe based on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a one pandas DataFrame like this,

```
    A   B  C
0  A0  B0  X
1  A1  B1  Y
2  A2  B2  X
```

And I want to merge the above with the following DataFrames,

```
df_x

    A   D
0  A0  X0
1  A1  X1
2  A2  X2
3  A3  X3
```

```
df_y 

    A   D
0  A0  Y0
1  A1  Y1
2  A2  Y2
3  A3  Y3
```

When merging I want a select the second DataFrame based on the column `C`. In here, if the value in `C` is `X` then I need to use `df_x` to merge with that row, and similarly if the value in `C` is `Y` use `df_y`. So, the final output would be like,

```
    A   B  C   D
0  A0  B0  X  X0
1  A1  B1  Y  Y1
2  A2  B2  X  X2
```

---

We may use some methods like, i) Iterating over each row and processing, or ii) Merging by adding `C` column for each `df_x` and `df_y` and then merging, etc. Obviously iterating method would not be much efficient. And the other method will consume additional space for a column with redundant data. Is there a *better* method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import io
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''A   B  C
0  A0  B0  X
1  A1  B1  Y
2  A2  B2  X'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')

df_x=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''    A   D
0  A0  X0
1  A1  X1
2  A2  X2
3  A3  X3'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')

df_y=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''    A   D
0  A0  Y0
1  A1  Y1
2  A2  Y2
3  A3  Y3'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')
# print(df)
# print(df_x)
# print(df_y)

dfx = df[df.C == 'X']
# print(dfx)

dfy = df[df.C == 'Y']
# print(dfy)

df1 = dfx.merge(df_x, left_on='A', right_on='A')
df2 = dfy.merge(df_y, left_on='A', right_on='A')
print(df1)
print(df2)

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('A')
```

Output

```
    A   B   C   D
0   A0  B0  X   X0
0   A1  B1  Y   Y1
1   A2  B2  X   X2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing it, however `merge` will do the job.

```
df_new = df.merge(df_x, 'left', ['A', 'B','C', 'D'],  suffixes=('*x', '*y')).groupby(lambda x: x.split('*')[0], axis=1).last()

df_new = df.merge(df_y, 'left', ['A', 'B','C', 'D'],  suffixes=('*x', '*y')).groupby(lambda x: x.split('*')[0], axis=1).last()
```

Try something like this. This is may not be the direct answer. But, you could easily do the job by understanding the above code.